# Pytorch to ONNX: Could not find an implementation for RandomNormalLike

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to convert a fairly complex model from pytorch into ONNX. The conversion succeeds without error, but I am encountering this error when loading the model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/***/***.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/***/***/***.py", line 38, in main
    ort_session = ort.InferenceSession(onnx_path, providers=[
  File "/home/***/miniconda3/envs/***/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
  File "/home/***/miniconda3/envs/***/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 369, in _create_inference_session
    sess.initialize_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NotImplemented: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 9 : NOT_IMPLEMENTED : Could not find an implementation for RandomNormalLike(1) node with name 'RandomNormalLike_598'
```

I think that the `RandomNormalLike` node the error is complaining about might correspond to this module I have:

```
class NoiseInjection(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(
        self,
        feat: torch.Tensor,
        noise: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
    ) -> torch.Tensor:
        if noise is None:
            batch, _, height, width = feat.shape
            noise = torch.randn(
                batch, 1, height, width,
                dtype=feat.dtype,
                device=feat.device,
            )

        return feat + self.weight * noise
```

I also created a different implementation, but it leads to the same error: (edit: This version actually works. I made an unrelated mistake elsewhere that mislead me into thinking it did not work)

```
    def forward(
        self,
        feat: torch.Tensor,
        noise: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
    ) -> torch.Tensor:
        if noise is None:
            noise = torch.randn_like(feat[:, 0:1])

        return feat + self.weight * noise
```

My pytorch and onnx version are as follows:

```
$ conda list torch
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
torch                     1.10.0+cu113             pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.10.0+cu113             pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.11.1+cu113             pypi_0    pypi

$ conda list onnx
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
onnx                      1.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
onnxruntime-gpu           1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

What can be done to be able to export such a module to onnx and run it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From checking online I found a similar issue on GitHub about conv (https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/3130), could be that the types of the parameters used in torch are not compatible with the implementation of RandomNormalLike available in ONNX.

Could you check in netron what's inside the RandomNormalLike node/nodes to see if they comply with the spec: https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#RandomNormal or https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#RandomNormalLike

Cheers

EDIT: turns out the RandomNormal node has a type of 10 which corresponds to fp16

While the onnxruntime implementation only supports float and doubles see source code here: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/24e35fba3217bf33b0e4064bc71d271a61938ba0/onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/generator/random.cc#L354

Solution here is either to run the whole model in fp32 or ask explicitely RandomNormalLike to use floats or doubles hoping that torch allows mixed computation on fp16 and fp32/fp64 I guess

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot actually find the actual offending node (RandomNormalLike_598), but am able to find RandomNormalLike_585, RandomNormalLike_595 ,RandomNormalLike_614 and RandomNormalLike_624.

RandomNormalLike_585 for example has such spec: 
{type: `RandomNormalLike`, name: `RandomNormalLike_585`, dtype: `10`, input: `name: 1409`, output: `name: 1410`}

Being unfamiliar with onnx so far, nothing strikes me as particularly odd.

Comment: that's odd to say the least. Any chance you have some small repro code somewhere like GitHub ?

Comment: Ah, actually, it seems dtype: `10` is meant to correspond to int64. But in Pytorch, my code takes the dtype from the input, and I would expect that to be either f32 or f16. I would have expected it to not be specified...

Comment: Let me work on a small repoduction then

Comment: integer dtype does look fishy indeed.

Comment: maybe feat.dtype is an integer here for some reason?

Comment: Looks to me that you found the issue, you have a noise injection on integers and ONNX does not implement RandomNormal for integers which seems reasonable :)

Comment: Ah, sorry I made some mistakes looking in netron:

--- I was looking at the wrong checkpoint file. The one causing the error does have RandomNormalLike_598, still with dtype 10.

--- dtype "10" might not actually correspond to int64. I got confused by the netron interface and I think it actually was saying that the "10" is an int64. The default dtype from the specs is "1" for RandomNormal so I do think dtype as written in the spec should be an int but I am not sure which data type "10" actually corresponds to

Comment: >>> import onnx
>>> onnx.mapping.TENSOR_TYPE_TO_NP_TYPE[10]
dtype('float16')

so that's weird :/

EDIT: maybe onnxruntime only supports fp32 or fp64

Comment: OK so found the code in onnxruntime, only supports float and double, I'll edit my answer

Comment: If my answer helped you can you let me know @LemmeTestThat by upvoting or marking my answer as valid? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to replicate this problem, I have made a minimal example. In the below code, `RandLike` works, while `RandReferenced` does not:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import onnxruntime as ort


class RandLike(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.randn_like(x[:, 0:1])


class RandReferenced(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        b, _ , w, h = x.shape
        return torch.randn(
            b, 1, w, h,
            device=x.device,
            dtype=x.dtype,
        )


module = RandLike().cuda().half()
dummy_input = torch.randn(2, 3, 4, 4, device='cuda').half()
torch.onnx.export(module, dummy_input, "randlike_2.onnx", input_names=["rand_input"], output_names=["rand_output"])
module = RandReferenced().cuda().half()
torch.onnx.export(module, dummy_input, "randReferenced_2.onnx", input_names=["rand_input"], output_names=["rand_output"])

ort_session = ort.InferenceSession("randlike_2.onnx", providers=[
    "CUDAExecutionProvider",
])
ort_session.run(["rand_output"], {"rand_input": dummy_input.cpu().numpy()})

ort_session = ort.InferenceSession("randReferenced_2.onnx", providers=[
    "CUDAExecutionProvider",
])
ort_session.run(["rand_output"], {"rand_input": dummy_input.cpu().numpy()})
```

Running the above code results in the below error:

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python random_like_onnx.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/***/random_like_onnx.py", line 32, in <module>
    ort_session = ort.InferenceSession("randReferenced_2.onnx", providers=[
  File "/home/***/miniconda3/envs/***/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
  File "/home/***/miniconda3/envs/***/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 369, in _create_inference_session
    sess.initialize_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NotImplemented: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 9 : NOT_IMPLEMENTED : Could not find an implementation for RandomNormalLike(1) node with name 'RandomNormalLike_1'
```